# Сохранение данных в формате json

Tags: c#, json, .net, telegram-bot

Первый раз пользуюсь json, по этому даже не знаю как правильно загуглить. Пишу бота для telegram. При пересылке сообщения из другого канала у меня в json должны записываться текст этого сообщения и FileId видео в этом сообщении. Собственно, всё работает. Но записывается не совсем в формате json (на картинке). То есть с таким же успехом я мог бы и в txt записывать. Хочу записывать в формате типа:

```
  {
   "Video": {
     "Caption": "блаблаблабла",
     "FileId": "KaKoYTOidTipa1337"
  }
```

Но совершенно не знаю как это сделать. Пишу вот такой код:

```
//путь к json файлу
string jsonFileName = "/Users/josephbreat/Projects/PonememiBot/PonememiBot/SandBox.json";
//сохраняю содержимое json'a в переменную
string jsonOldString = File.ReadAllText(jsonFileName);
//сохраняю в переменную старое содержимое + новое содержимое (Caption и FileID)
string jsonString = jsonOldString + message?.Caption + "\r" + message?.Video?.FileId + "\r" + "\r";
//записываю содержимое переменной в json файл
File.WriteAllText(jsonFileName, jsonString);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что бы получить json объекта нужно использовать сериализацию  string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(object);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать модель данных

```
public class Data
{
    public VideoInfo Video { get; set; }
}

public class VideoInfo
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string FileId { get; set; }
}
```

Подключить неймспейс

```
using System.Text.Json;
```

Написать код

```
Data data = new Data()
{
    Video = new VideoInfo()
    {
        Caption = "блаблаблабла",
        FileId = "KaKoYTOidTipa1337"
    }
};
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);
File.WriteAllText(json);
```

Если нужен красивый вывод для отладки

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    WriteIndented = true,
    Encoder = JavaScriptEncoder.UnsafeRelaxedJsonEscaping
};
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, options);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только у меня получается json с лишними скобочками. Не подскажете, как исправить? Вот ссылка на код и результат - https://gist.github.com/joeybreat/317c624ecd796320c91df8c977dd0cb7

Comment: У меня выходит что я как бы новый json присоединяю к старому. А не добавляю в json со старыми данными новые данные

Comment: @joeybreat а вам что нужно? Коллекцию сохранить, так сохраняйте коллекцию. Забудьте про конкатенацию строк. `List<Data> list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<Data>>(File.ReadAllText("file.json"));` потом `list.Add(data)` потом `File.WriteAllText("file.json", JsonSerializer.Serialize(list, options));` все просто. Вы работаете с данными, а не с текстом. То естьл сериализуйте не по одному элементу, а сразу списком. Либо сойздайне новый список `List<Data> list = new();` и наполните его изначальными данными, а потом сериализуйте.